# Return the field by translating to language code which is specified in the url using Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

My model:

```
class Languages(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
class Translate(models.Model):
    lang_code = models.ForeignKey(Languages,related_name = 'translate',  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ncode = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

My view:

```
class Languages_List(mixins.ListModelMixin):
      queryset = Languages.objects.all()
      serializer_class = LanguagesSerializer

   def get_queryset(self):
       queryset = Languages.objects.all()
       lang = self.request.query_params.get('ncode',None)
       queryset = queryset.filter(translate__ncode=lang)

   return queryset
```

My serializer:

```
  class LanguagesSerializer(QueryFieldsMixin,serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Languages
        fields = ('id', 'code','name')
```

I am able return the result by filtering my nested field with spanish translation.my url looks like:

```
GET /lang/?ncode=sp
```

Now my result is :
[image]

when I filter using spanish my name(english) should translate to spanish as shown below and return the result without changing the database. How to achieve this using Django?

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "code": "en",
  "name": "Inglés",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get only the desired related records, you can specify the list of fields to return:

```
queryset = Languages.objects.filter(translate__ncode=lang).values(
        'id', 
        'code', 
        'name',
        'translate__ncode',
        'translate__name'
        )
```

This would give you a dictionary with the specified field names as keys, and it would only include the ncode from the query filter.

Don't know though whether and how `values()` would work in the context of a Model serializer.